# Preventing changes made in modal until save

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog

I am trying to use a modal to allow users to edit a previously saved selection. The problem I'm having is that changes within the modal are saved instantly instead of only after the user clicks save. So, if a user makes changes within the modal, and then cancels, the changes are still saved.

Any suggestions on how to prevent changes until the user clicks save?

```
.controller('EditProjectCtrl',
    function ($location, $stateParams, Projects, $modalInstance) {
      var editProject = this;
      var projectId = $stateParams.projectId,
        projectIndex;

      editProject.projects = Projects;
      projectIndex = editProject.projects.$indexFor(projectId);
      editProject.project = editProject.projects[projectIndex];
      editProject.options = [
        {'type': 'Small', 'cost': 10},
        {'type': 'Medium', 'cost': 10},
        {'type': 'Large', 'cost': 10}
            ];

      editProject.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
     };

      editProject.destroy = function () {
        $modalInstance.close(editProject.selected);
        editProject.projects.$remove(editProject.project).then(function (data) {
          $location.path('/selection');
        });
      };
      $modalInstance.result.then(function(selectedItem) {
        editProject.selected = selectedItem;
      },
      editProject.save = function () {
        $modalInstance.close(editProject.selected);
        editProject.projects.$save(editProject.project).then(function (data) {
          $location.path('/selection');
         });
      })
    })
```

Comment: 2 approached for this. First is to pass copy of your Projects object and only assign the value on confirm. Second is to serialize a copy of your Projects object to JSON and, on Cancel, assign the serialized value to Projects object overwriting changes.

Comment: @Dave Alperovich Thank you. If I use the first option, would you suggest using the angular.copy function somewhat similar to this [egghead post](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-angular-copy-for-deep-copy)?

Comment: Yes, `angular.copy()` is ideal